# openERP product account setting

Tags: odoo, product, account

I am new to OpenERP. I have installed OpenERP 7 and configured accounting module with UK standard. 
I have created sample item with following setting
- Category->All products
- Product Type -> Stockable Product
- not set any a/c in the accounting tab

after creating the above product, I have created Purchase Order (supplier payment is not done). The transaction is record in Profit and Loss as Cost of sales. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't set up the accounts on the product, it should fall back to the defaults on the company under Settings -> Company.  Check to see what you have defined there.

Comment: Ok got the point. When defining a stockable product what will be the Income and Expense accounts should mention in the product creation?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when purchasing or selling a product, it will first consider the account specified in the product. If there is no account for the product, then will consider the account specified in the product category. If here also account is not specified then will consider the account specified in the selected fiscal position.

Comment: Ok got the point. When defining a stockable product what will be the Income and Expense accounts should mention in the product creation?

Comment: if the income and expense accounts are different for every product,then you have to mention in products otherwise mention in the product's category

Comment: I can define accounts in product category level. I have create product category called "Saleable" and define account entries as follows : income -> "Sales Category" Expense-> "Cost of sales". After that i have created a product under this category. Then I have created a Purchase order using this product and proceed to "Validate invoice" step. Still the payment is pending. This transaction posted a cost of sales entry to the Profit and loss. Why is that? cost of sale is applicable when selling a product.

Comment: Any suggestion for above issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem go to Sale > Product > choose that product (or one of them) you want to invoice it, on product catagory, click on it to show catagory page (in edit mode click icon next to dropdown box) and in Account Properties can fine Income Account, select it and all the problem solve.